# gdb watchpoint on struct variables

Tags: linux, gdb, watchpoint

I have a structure like this :

```
    struct A 
    {
        int a; 
        char b; 
    };
```

this structure is referenced at various places in a large code. The pointer to this struct is passed on to different functions and accordingly the variables in this structure are updated. i want to set a watchpoint on variable a in this struct as it travels across many functions. to see how a changes. How do I set this watch point ?

Answer (score 8):

First set a *breakpoint* where you create an instance of your struct using *break*, like

```
break myfile.c:9
```

Then just use *watch* to set a watchpoint, like

```
watch myStructInstance.a
```

for variable *a* or

```
watch *0x7ffff75177f0
```

for a memory address. The memory address can be obtained easily by using *print*, like

```
print &myStructInstance.a
```

Now every time variable a or the given memory address gets modified gdb will break.

Comment: One gotcha: If the struct pointer variable changes, you will need to pass the `-l|-location` flag. `watch -l foo->bar` will watch this particular instance of `foo` at the point the watch is registered, even if `foo` itself changes.

Answer (score 4):

I come with the same problem when debugging my virtual memory simulator. The problem is how to keep a close look at the data inside structs.

I tried using print to check, but that's too noisy. Because I have to print out more than 15 variables.

I also tried using watchpoint, but on my machine, I can only set no more than 4 hardware watchpoints. That's not even close to my goal.

Finally, I find my solution by using user-defined function in .gdbinit file. e.g. if I want to watch array of my structure, using

```
define lookintoStructs
    if mystruct != 0x0
        print mystruct[0]
        print mystruct[1]
        print mystruct[2]
        print mystruct[3]
        print mystruct[4]
        print mystruct[5]
    end
end
```

to make it more convenient to use, I'd like to make it hook to my next instruction in gdb.

```
define hook-next
    lookintoStructs
end
```

so when I call next or n in gdb, lookintoStructs could be called automatically. works fine for me.